# OpenCV trackers not recognized (AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerKCF_create')

Tags: python, opencv, object-tracking

```
import cv2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    major_v, minor_v, subminor_v = (cv2.__version__).split('.')
    # >>> 4.6.0
    tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
    # >>> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerKCF_create'
```

As the code above shows, when running this these are the results I get (I have tried this with other trackers in cv2 and other than `TrackerMIL_create` all trackers that are supposed to be included are giving me this error. I used
`pip install opencv-python`,
`pip install opencv-contrib-python`, and
`pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless`
on my terminal to try and install opencv. I haven't run into any other issues with cv2 attributes (such as `imread`, `imshow`, `resize`) but the trackers are giving me a hard time and I was wondering if there is anything I am doing wrong from the start. Thanks.

Comment: Did you install `opencv-contrib-python`? `TrackerKCF_create()` is not in the regular `opencv-python` module.

Comment: Yes, I installed `opencv-contrib-python`, `opencv-python`, and `opencv-contrib-python-headless` and nothing seems to work

Comment: If you still have everything installed, remove everything and then reinstall `opencv-contrib-python`. The packages can conflict with one another. `pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python opencv-python opencv-contrib-python-headless && pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: @wkl -- You could consider making this an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Remove everything and then reinstall `opencv-contrib-python`. The packages can conflict with one another. `pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python opencv-python opencv-contrib-python-headless && pip install opencv-contrib-python`